# Local Notification IONIC schedule on Monday and Tuesday

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic-framework, localnotification

So I want my Local notification to send a notification every Monday and Tuesday in every week until disabled manually.

Only figured out how to do 1 day or ALL the days so far.

```
this.localNotifications.schedule({
    title: "title",
    id: 1, // used later to cancel
    text: 'Single Local Notification',
    data: { secret: 'secret' },
    lockscreen: true,
    icon: "../../assets/icon/favicon.png", 
    trigger: {
           'every': {
              'weekday': 1,
              'hour': 10,
              'minute': 40
           }
         },
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't trigger repeat notification by `every`  TriggerUnit. So we need to calculate the upcoming timestamp on which notification should fire.

```
    //monday 
    var d = new Date();
    var monday = d.setDate(d.getDate() + ((7 - d.getDay()) % 7 + 1) % 7); //timestamp of monday

    //tuesday
    var tuesday = d.setDate(d.getDate() + ((7 - d.getDay()) % 7 + 2) % 7); ////timestamp of tuesday

    var timeToSent = monday;
    if (monday > tuesday) {
            timeToSent = tuesday;
    }


Now we have the least timestamp either of Monday or Tuesday.so now 

    trigger: {at: timeToSent},
```

This way You can send notifications to your selected time.